# Java <identifier> expected with writeObject()

Tags: java, compiler-errors

For a class assignment, I'm required to write an object to a file. Our professor gave us a section of code to complete this, but apparently it's wrong because I'm getting an error. Here's my code.

```
class InvMaintenance {

    //create an OutputStream to write data to a file
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(inven.dat);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

    final long MAX_SIZE = 100; //constant for array length
    Inventory cInventory = new Inventory(MAX_SIZE); //instantiate Inventory object
    oos.writeObject(cInventory); //write initial Inventory to file  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Output options
        /*  Inventory Maintenance
            1) Add Item
            2) Remove Item
            3) Sell Item
            4) Receive Item
            5) Display Inventory
            6) Quit
            Please Select NUMBER: */

        //switch on options
        //call appropriate method

        oos.writeObject(cInventory);
        oos.close();
    }
}
```

My error is occuring on the line `oos.writeObject(cInventory);`

```
Item.java:150: <identifier> expected
    oos.writeObject(cInventory);            //write initial Inventory to file   
                   ^
Item.java:150: <identifier> expected
    oos.writeObject(cInventory);            //write initial Inventory to file   
                              ^
2 errors
```

And yes, for some reason it's saying this is two separate errors that are... exactly the same.

Any help debugging would be appreciated. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that had to be in the main-method

```
//create an OutputStream to write data to a file
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(inven.dat);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

Inventory cInventory = new Inventory(MAX_SIZE); //instantiate Inventory object
```

changed Code:

```
class InvMaintenance {

    final static long MAX_SIZE = 100;          //constant for array length

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Output options
            /*  Inventory Maintenance
                1) Add Item
                2) Remove Item
                3) Sell Item
                4) Receive Item
                5) Display Inventory
                6) Quit
                Please Select NUMBER: */

        //switch on options
        //call appropriate method

        //create an OutputStream to write data to a file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(inven.dat);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

        Inventory cInventory = new Inventory(MAX_SIZE); //instantiate Inventory object

        oos.writeObject(cInventory);
        oos.close();
    }   

}
```

Hint: change the constant to final static long .. it you use static the values is copied on compile time

Hint2: take care of the exceptions ..

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I have a slew of other errors to contend with now, but the error in question appears to be resolved. The hints were especially helpful!

Comment: take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8960321/1158170) .. there are a lot of other useful hints

Answer (score 0):

The compiler complains about the following line:

```
oos.writeObject(cInventory);            //write initial Inventory to file
```

You can't have freestanding code like this outside all methods. Move it into `main()`.

Variable declarations that precede it (`FileOutputStream fos ...`) should probably also be moved into `main()`. They would compile as they are now, but would cause you problems later on.

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the javadoc of the [`writeObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29) method, it throws an `IOException`. So you should either catch the exception by setting the statement in a `try-catch` block, or let your main method throw the exception

Further, you are trying to access non-static fields from a static context which won't work either.

Last, your statement `oos.writeObject(cInventory);` outside your main method will not work either as you cannot have statements lying around in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Executable code such as method calls must be inside either a method or possibly a static block, but in your case it belongs clearly inside the `main` method. Move the code there and it will work.

Furthermore, the `main` method is the program entry point. Unless the control flow has some way of going from inside the `main` method to the code you want to execute, nothing will happen anway.

Answer (score 0):

where you define the following code?

```
//create an OutputStream to write data to a file
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(inven.dat);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

final long MAX_SIZE = 100;          //constant for array length
Inventory cInventory = new Inventory(MAX_SIZE); //instantiate Inventory object

oos.writeObject(cInventory);            //write initial Inventory to file
```

you have your class, you have a "main method", but where goes the code?
Additional thing: what it "inven.dat"

BTW, if you have compilation error, you can't really debug your code, because your code should be compiler beforehands...